# Изменение модели контекста EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Не могу найти как отключить кэширование модели контекста EF. По первоначальной задумке предполагал сделать внешний ключ от таблицы **Weather** к таблице **Year**. Все отлично отработало. Потом от этой идеи отказался. Но после удаления БД и перезапуска приложения модель объекта `modelBuilder` на входе метода `OnModelCreating()` все равно содержит этот внешний ключ. Подскажи как EF управляет изменением этой модели?

Код класса контекста:

```
    public class WeatherContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Weather> WeatherData { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Year> Years { get; set; }
    
            public WeatherContext(DbContextOptions<WeatherContext> options) : base(options)
            {
            }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>().ToTable("Weather");
                modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>().Property(p => p.Wind).IsRequired(false);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>().Property(p => p.WindSpeed).IsRequired(false);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>().Property(p => p.Cloudiness).IsRequired(false);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>().Property(p => p.LowerCloudiness).IsRequired(false);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>().Property(p => p.HorizontalVisibility).IsRequired(false);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Year>().ToTable("Year");
            }
        }
```

Модели:

```
public class Weather
    {
        public int WeatherID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public float Temperature { get; set; }
        public float Humidity { get; set; }
        public float DewPoint { get; set; }
        public int Pressure { get; set; }
        public string Wind { get; set; }
        public int? WindSpeed { get; set; }
        public int? Cloudiness { get; set; }
        public int? LowerCloudiness { get; set; }
        public string HorizontalVisibility { get; set; }
        public string Conditions { get; set; }
        //public int YearID { get; set; }
        //public Year Year { get; set; }
    }

    public class Year
    {
        public int YearID { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Weather> WeatherData { get; set; }
    }
```

Debug-view модели, создаваемой EF:

```
Model: 
  EntityType: Weather
    Properties: 
      WeatherID (int) Required PK AfterSave:Throw ValueGenerated.OnAdd
      Cloudiness (int?)
      Conditions (string)
      Date (DateTime) Required
      DewPoint (float) Required
      HorizontalVisibility (string)
      Humidity (float) Required
      LowerCloudiness (int?)
      Pressure (int) Required
      Temperature (float) Required
      Wind (string)
      WindSpeed (int?)
      YearID (no field, int?) Shadow FK Index
    Keys: 
      WeatherID PK
    Foreign keys: 
      Weather {'YearID'} -> Year {'YearID'} ToDependent: WeatherData ClientSetNull
    Indexes: 
      YearID <unnamed>
  EntityType: Year
    Properties: 
      YearID (int) Required PK AfterSave:Throw ValueGenerated.OnAdd
      Name (int) Required
    Navigations: 
      WeatherData (ICollection<Weather>) Collection ToDependent Weather
    Keys: 
      YearID PK
```

Comment: `public ICollection<Weather> WeatherData { get; set; }` - а как иначе без ключа отслеживать эти данные?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, понял откуда эти связи взялись

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть связи. Для работы связей нужны ключи. Так что тут они в любом случае будут.
Другой вопрос я бы посоветовал не описывать модель в OnModelCreating как у вас. Муторно и долго использовать fluent API как по мне. Есть атрибут [Required]. Его можно вешать на свойства в самой модели:

```
public class Year
{
    public int YearID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Weather> WeatherData { get; set; }
}
```

Тем самым избавитесь от постоянной нужды лезть в контекст и править его.
Так же если нужно называть таблицу так же как имя класса, то можно ничего не писать. Энтити сама так делает по-умолчанию. Без необходимости писать:  `modelBuilder.Entity<Weather>().ToTable("Weather");`

Comment: Да, спасибо, понял откуда появился внешний ключ. С названием таблиц тоже применил. Остальные строки в OnModelCreating тоже в итоге убрал, оказалось что для nullable-типов EF их и так создает колонки как NULL

Comment: С названием таблиц все-так не совсем так. EF по умолчанию использует для названий имена свойств в контексте, т.е. в моем случае по умолчанию таблица будет называться ***WeatherData***.

Comment: Да, названия свойств из контекста. Прошу прощения этот момент я не так выразил. Но что мешает назвать свойство как класс? :)

Comment: Не, ничего не мешает. Так и сделал)